# MasterPage/ContentPage with NVelocity and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages, mvccontrib, viewengine, nvelocity

I am a big fan of NVelocity. I think its terse syntax is a huge boon, and helps keep my views simple and effective. I have begun using the NVelocity view engine from the Mvc Contrib project for ASP.NET MVC, along with the Castle NVelocity .vm syntax highlighter.

While I love what NVelocity brings to the table, I am really missing one feature of ASP.NET .aspx views that I find immensely useful: Master Pages.

Does anyone know if there is an NVelocity view engine for ASP.NET MVC that provides Master/Child pages like classic .aspx views? Does the MVCContrib project from Codeplex support this (at the moment there is a total void of documentation for the MVCContrib NVelocity view engine.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, the NVelocity View Engine for ASP.NET MVC does have some basic master/child content capabilities. There is a simple #parse() command that may be used to render child views...when used with the $childContent template variable, a simple master/content page relationship is born:

```
<head>
  <title>My Page with Master Page</title>
  <link href="$Url.Content('~/Views/Common/Site.css')" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    #parse("shared/header.vm")
  </div>
  <form>
  <div id="content">
    #parse($childContent)
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    #parse("shared/footer.vm");
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
```